# Для чего нужная такого вида запись создания экземпляра класса

Tags: php

```
(new Class($params))->methodName($params_to);
```

для чего это используется? какие кейсы для использования такого вида записи?

Comment: Когда функционал класса надо а обжект не надо. Ну и так меньше писать. Всё.

Comment: В данном варианте в класс передаются параметры и метод выполняет действия не требующие возвращаемого значения. Если в функции которая считая a и b необходимо вернуть результат, то здесь результатом является метод, который может что-то переопределить или же изменить, без надобности возвращать результат.

Comment: @MoloF масло-масляное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экономия на строчках кода и переменных.

Используется либо когда экземпляр класса создается для вызова одного единственного метода (хотя в этом случае я бы подумал о `static` функции), либо когда метод возвращает объект и можно организовать цепочку вызовов

```
(new Class($params))->
   method1($params1)->
   method2($params2)->
   method3($params3);
```

Comment: Можно примеры какие нибудь, когда и где такое используется?

Comment: @dasauser Так я же написал все в ответе

Comment: я имел ввиду физические примеры, типа "когда нужно записать пользователя" или что-то в этом роде. просто я сам не могу придумать ситуации (кроме инициализации экземпляра приложения в public/Index.php), где я мог бы это использовать.

Comment: @dasauser не так уж часто подобное встречается. Обычно, когда сам объект не нужен, а результат метода нужен. Например хотите файл в папке найти. Поиск через папку. нужен только сам файл(ы): `$files  = (new Folder("/some/path"))->find("*.jpg");`

Comment: @teran, окей, спасибо.